# Find value in array of structs

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

I have an array of structs in my script, and I need to check inside the entire array of structs if somewhere inside a struct, the "id" key has a specific value.

I could do this with a loop, but is there any better/faster way to do this? Note that it needs to be compatible with ColdFusion 8, so ArrayFind is not available.

Comment: Better in what way? Is the array _really_ an arbitrary structure? Why not give an example of what it looks like? What is the source of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Peter suggests, it's hard to say definitely given the paucity of info provided, but *if* the key value is likely to be unique in the data structure, the you could use [`structFindValue()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structfindvalue.html) to locate it. The challenge here is that it does not pay attention to the KEY that the value is in. I do not know what Adobe / Macromedia were thinking in providing `structFindKey()` and `structFindValue()`, but no `structFindKeyValue()`.

On a whim I checked [CFLib](http://www.cflib.org/) to see if there was a UDF to cover that ground. Not only is there one, it seems I wrote it (my memory is like a sieve sometimes): [`structFindKeyWithValue()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/structFindKeyWithValue). That's written for CF9, but it shouldn't take too much to back-port it to CF8.

This is a bit of a general answer. If you provide better info, we can give a better answer.

Comment: 10 points for the use of the word "paucity" in a sentence. nicely done :)

Comment: I'd agree with the 10 pts for using "paucity". But I think Adam should get another 10 for showing the marks of a true developer. He saw a problem, thought "There should be a UDF for this", looked it up and found a UDF that he, himself, wrote. THIS is why I always love reading Adam. :-)